# Qt Phonon does not play videos

Tags: windows, qt, video, phonon

I have an application that displays some predefined messages and videos using the **Phonon** resources from the **Qt** library. It always worked very well until recently when access to the machine running the application has to be done over the network. Now, from more than 30 videos, only one is correctly displayed.

All videos are played normally (the **K-Lite** codec pack is installed) with **Windows Media Player** or **Media Player Classic**. But the application doesn't play them.

What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Phonon uses system plugins to play videos. If you have videos using for example H.264 format, default directshow plugin can’t play it. There is alternative plugins like [vlc](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/phonon/phonon-vlc) plugin and [mplayer](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/phonon/phonon-mplayer) plugin available.

Note that while they reside in KDE project, they are pure Qt plugins and just hosted (and developed) by KDE; they are part of getting Phonon working in Windows with KDE. I didn’t find any prebuilt modules (KDE distribution should have some though), but compiling those by yourself should be relatively easy.

Comment: That's the problem, before the update, it just was working fine. After that it simple stopped working. [K-Line](http://www.codecguide.com/) is installed as a way to provide more video plugins.

Comment: Which Phonon backend you use?